# Magento2 Checkout Default Topmenu and Basket

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, frontend

I want to show the **default topmenu (incl. basket ) in the onepage checkout**.

I think that this part is important:

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
```

But if i add this into my custom checkout_index_index.xml it wont work!
I also see, that the page_layout/checkout.xml has an update handle empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On checkout page top menu is displaying but just applying css, dispaly none

If you want to display top menu on checkout page then you have to change checkout page CSS

```
.checkout-index-index .nav-sections, .checkout-index-index .nav-toggle {
 display: none;
}
```

to

```
.checkout-index-index .nav-sections, .checkout-index-index .nav-toggle {
 display: block;
}
```

For display logo, you have to add code in file

> `app/design/frontend/YourTheme/Package/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: And what about the logo .. this still not appear

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Are you sure about header-wrapper .. cause in checkout.xml there is:

<container name="checkout.header.container" as="checkout_header_container" label="Checkout Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content">
            <container name="checkout.header.wrapper" label="Checkout Page Header" as="checkout_header_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content"/>
        </container>

Comment: If i add a custom checkout_index_index like this:

`code`<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
    </body>
</page>`code`

Comment: Everything is broken ...

if i do this:

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
    </body>
</page>

than it works .. but it seems wrong from structure

Comment: See my updated answer for complete code,

Answer (score 1):

You need to override checkout_index_index.xml in your themes folder.
/app/design/frontend/**vendor/theme**/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />           
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>            
    </body>
</page>
```